# Parsing XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-objects

I am newbie to LINQ/XML. I just learned that Language integrated queries can be used for parsing xml. I am trying to parse the following XML structure and I need help

==================================

```
<config>

<params>
  <tp name="abc">yes</tp>
  <tp name="aee">no</tp>
  <tp name="bbc">no</tp>
  <tp name="ccb">yes</tp>
</params>

<nits>
  <tn name="kjh">
    <min>44</min>
    <max>98</max> 
  </tn>

  <tn name="klm">
    <min>55</min>
    <max>88</max> 
  </tn>

  <tn name="hhh">
    <min>44</min>
    <max>98</max> 
  </tn>
</nits>

<params>
  <tp name="lml">no</tp>
  <tp name="rre">yes</tp>
  <tp name="rst">no</tp>
  <tp name="wee">yes</tp>
</params>

<nits>
  <tn name="adf">
    <min>44</min>
    <max>98</max> 
  </tn>

  <tn name="ddd">
    <min>42</min>
    <max>92</max> 
  </tn>

  <tn name="kjj">
    <min>92</min>
    <max>98</max> 
  </tn>
</nits>

</config>
```

==================================

Output needed :

My objective is to show the above data as key value pairs by the category in a text file or a data grid etc.

```
<Params>
abc : yes
aee : no
bbc : yes
...
...
...
...


<nits>

kjh: 44 , 98
klm: 55 , 88
...
...
kjj: 92 , 98
ddd: 42 , 92
...
```

The code I have written so far is,

```
static void QueryTheData(XDocument doc)
        {
            try
            {
                var a = doc.Descendants("config").Elements("params");
                var b = doc.Descendants("config").Elements("nits");

                var c = doc.Elements("tp");
                var d = doc.Elements("tn");

               /* to do :  parse the elements into key value pairs */
               /* Need hint or help to proceed to get key value pairs from xml data

            }
             catch(Exception e)
            {
                 ....
            }               
 }
```

ANy good pointers for beginner's LINQ/XML C# is also needed.

thanks in advance,
ak

Comment: Seems like a splendid job for XSLT

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var fs = new StreamReader("./test.xml"))
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(fs);

            var parms = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements("params/tp")
                .ToDictionary(el => el.Attribute("name").Value, el => el.Value);

            var nits = doc.Root.XPathSelectElements("nits/tn")
                .Select(el => new {
                        Name = el.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Min  = (int) el.Element("min"),
                        Max  = (int) el.Element("max")
                    }).ToList();

            foreach (var kvp in parms)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

            foreach (var nit in nits
                    .OrderBy(nit => nit.Name)
                    .ThenBy(nit => nit.Max))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", nit.Name, nit.Min, nit.Max);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This shows you a few of the ingredients, including different approaches to storing params/nits in collection types. Output:

```
abc: yes
aee: no
bbc: no
ccb: yes
lml: no
rre: yes
rst: no
wee: yes
adf: 44 98
ddd: 42 92
hhh: 44 98
kjh: 44 98
kjj: 92 98
klm: 55 88
```

Comment: Output seems to be exactly what the doctor prescribed now

Answer (score 1):

**"ANy good pointers for beginner's LINQ/XML C# is also needed."**

You might find [.NET Language-Integrated Query for XML Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx) helpful which talks about using LINQ to XML.

Comment: Absolutely not - `XmlReader` would make it *much* harder than using LINQ to XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet Which is why answer is including LINQ to XML as well as XmlReader.

Comment: ... and now you've given an example which is clearly about a piece of XML which is nothing to do with the OP's sample, and doesn't use `XmlReader` and `StringBuilder` that you talked about at the start...

Comment: The answer doesn't include it. It includes *links*, one of which talks about LINQ to XML, but which doesn't give any specific guidance to the OP. Sorry, this just isn't a good answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet The op said "ANy good pointers for beginner's LINQ/XML C# is also needed." I believe I provided that information along with an example that can be adopted suit the OP's XML.

Comment: At the very *least* you should have given better link text - given that it's in a sentence starting "For information on how to do this" anyone would *expect* it to be about `XmlReader` and `StringBuilder`. As for adapting your code... I see *very* little of it which would be relevant to the OP. There's not much point in posting a large clump of code which is only tangentially related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the `name` attribute and the text value from each `<tp>` element? That's easy:

```
// Parameters
var query = doc.Descendants("tp")
               .Select(tp => new { Name = tp.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   Value = tp.Value });

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", result.Name, result.Value);
}
```

And similarly for the min/max part:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("tn")
               .Select(tn => new { Name = tn.Attribute("name").Value,
                                   Min = (int) tn.Element("min"),
                                   Max = (int) tn.Element("max") });

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", result.Name, result.Min, result.Max);
}
```

This assumes that the XML follows the schema you've laid out, of course - it will fail if the elements don't have the right children or attributes.

Comment: Oh sweet. I didn't [know about conversion operators on XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340386(v=vs.95).aspx)s :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's answer will do the trick for selecting the params part of your output.

> Any good pointers for beginner's LINQ/XML C# is also needed.

I recommend [C# in Depth, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471), by Jon Skeet.  This is overall a great C# book, and it includes some LINQ to XML material.  While you're waiting for the book to arrive, and as a LINQ to XML supplement to the book, I'd recommend [Microsoft's LINQ to XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).